# Limit usando group_contact no MySQL 5

Tags: mysql

Bom dia pessoal, estou com uma dúvida:

Tenho o seguinte SQL de exemplo:

```
group_concat( DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS `images`
```

No SEPARATOR preciso definir uma quantidade ao invés de trazer todas os itens.
No MariaDB consigo fazer isso apenas passado o Limite ao final. Exemplo:

```
group_concat( DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' LIMIT 4 ) AS `images
```

Más no MySQL 5.7.32 da erro de sintaxes. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando a função do MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX

A Consulta final ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order`),
  ',',
  4
) AS `images`
```